# Make minimize the width of the bootstrap 3 dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below is my snippets, as you can see on the dropdown menu, its width is big so I want to make its width equal to the parent trigger button, Anyone knows how to make it?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                      test
                      <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right downloadoptions">
                      <li role="presentation"><a class="tbcopy" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">COPY</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a class="tbpdf" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">PDF</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a class="tbcsv" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">CSV</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a class="tbexcel" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">EXCEL</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a class="tbprint" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">PRINT</a></li>
                    </ul>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override the default `min-width` of the dropdown menu:

```css
.downloadoptions {
    min-width: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    test
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right downloadoptions">
    <li role="presentation"><a class="tbcopy" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">COPY</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a class="tbpdf" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">PDF</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a class="tbcsv" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">CSV</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a class="tbexcel" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">EXCEL</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a class="tbprint" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">PRINT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
dropdown-menu { 
 width: 69px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  }
```